# for x in y(): how does this work?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I was looking for code to spin a cursor in the terminal and found this. I was wondering what was happening in the code. In particular `for c in spinning_cursor():` I've never seen this syntax. Is it because I am returning one element from a generator at a time with `yield`, and this is assigned to c? Any other examples of this for x in y() use?

```
import sys
import time

def spinning_cursor():
    cursor='/-\|'
    i = 0
    while 1:
        yield cursor[i]
        i = (i + 1) % len(cursor)

for c in spinning_cursor():
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\b')
```

Comment: Another example? for i in range(10): print(i)

Comment: you may find everything just here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Using `yield` turns a function into a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). A generator is a specialized type of [iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). `for` always loops over iterables, taking each element in turn and assigning it to the name(s) you listed.

`spinning_cursor()` returns a generator, the code inside `spinning_cursor()` doesn't actually run until you start iterating over the generator. Iterating over a generator means the code in the function is executed until it comes across a `yield` statement, at which point the result of the expression there is returned as the next value and execution is paused again.

The `for` loop does just that, it'll call the equivalent of [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on the generator, until the generator signals it is done by raising `StopIteration` (which happens when the function returns). Each return value of `next()` is assigned, in turn, to `c`.

You can see this by creating the generator on in the Python prompt:

```
>>> def spinning_cursor():
...     cursor='/-\|'
...     i = 0
...     while 1:
...         yield cursor[i]
...         i = (i + 1) % len(cursor)
... 
>>> sc = spinning_cursor()
>>> sc
<generator object spinning_cursor at 0x107a55eb0>
>>> next(sc)
'/'
>>> next(sc)
'-'
>>> next(sc)
'\\'
>>> next(sc)
'|'
```

This specific generator never returns, so `StopIteration` is never raised and the `for` loop will go on forever unless you kill the script.

A far more boring (but more efficient) alternative would be to use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

spinning_cursor = cycle('/-\|')
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. The idea is to call a function and while it is processing, display this spinning cursor. When it is finished processing it is stopped. So I will work on that. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, the for statement lets you iterate over elements.

According the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) :

> Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence

Here, the element will be the return value of `spinning_cursor()`.

Answer (score 3):

The `for c in spinning_cursor()` syntax is a `for-each` loop. It's going to iterate through each item in the iterator returned by `spinning_cursor()`.

The inside of the loop will:

1. Write the character to standard out and flush so it displays.
2. Sleep for a tenth of a second
3. Write `\b`, which is interpreted as a backspace (deletes the last character). Notice this happens at the end of the loop so it won't be written during the first iteration, and that it shares the flush call in step 1.

`spinning_cursor()` is going to return a [generator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators), which doesn't actually run until you start iterating. It looks like it will loop through `'/-\|'`, in order, forever. It's kind of like having an infinite list to iterate through.

So, the final output is going to be an ASCII spinner. You'll see these characters (in the same spot) repeating until you kill the script.

```
/
-
\
|
```

Answer (score 3):

Martijn Pieters explanation is excellent. Below is another implementation of the same code you had in the question. it uses [itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to produce the same result as `spinning_cursor`.  itertools is filled with excellent examples of iterators and functions to help create your own iterators. It might help you understand iterators better.

```
import sys, time, itertools

for c in itertools.cycle('/-\|'):
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\b')
```

Answer (score 2):

the spinning_cursor function returns an iterable (a generator from yield).

```
for c in spinning_cursor():
```

would be the same as

```
 for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
```